# Passing variable from PHP to Smarty

Tags: php, variables, smarty

I had two script, one in .php and one in .tpl
I need to pass the variable in php to the tpl.
I tried this one, but nothinng works (but somehow

1. it works for one or two days, and after that,
2. it showed blank,
3. if i create another **php script** just to echo the variable, it works.

PHP Code:

```
<?php
$usdidr2 = "12610.198648";
$usdidr2 =  number_format($usdidr,2,',','.');
echo $usdidr2;
session_start();
$regValue = $usdidr2;
$_SESSION['regUSDIDR1'] = $regValue;
?>
```

SMARTY Code:

```
<li>
    <a href="example.php"><strong>
        {php}
            session_start();
            $regValue = $_SESSION['regUSDIDR1'];
            $regValue2 = number_format(45.99*$regValue,2,',','.');
            echo "Rp. ".$regValue."";
            print_r($regValue);
        {/php}
    </strong></a>
</li>
```

Comment: Use... ehm.. I don't know... smarty? `$smarty->assign()` Or... ehm... read [manuals](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/)?

Comment: Even though the question is a bit vague, I'd assume your session's expired ;)

Comment: RTFM! RTFM! RTFM! RTFM! (chars limit)

Comment: @KarolyHorvath, yes it showed null (blank) variables in smarty after 1 or 2 days. (not stop working, but maybe the session expired or something i can't comprehend)

Comment: @Havelock most probably, the session...but how do i get rid of this? thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use this syntax:

```
$res = "Hello World!";
$this->context->smarty->assign('result', $res);
```

And passing to .tpl file like this:

```
{$result}
```

Hope  this helping you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the syntax to send data from php to tpl

```
$smarty->assign('variable name with which you can access the data in tpl', $php_data_you_want_to_send);
```

**Update:**

```
$smarty->assign('rate',$usdidr2);// you just need to write rate without $
```

You can access it in smarty like `{$rate}` if it is string
You can access it in smarty like `{$rate|print_r}` if it is array

Comment: how do I fetch it in SMARTY code?
I tried this one:
$smarty->assign('$rate','$usdidr2');

and in smarty: {$rate}
but null still

Comment: @moengoet Can you please post what exactly you have tried so i can have and idea

Comment: <li>
    <a href="example.php"><strong>
        {$rate}
    </strong></a>
</li>

Comment: @moengoet its correct on the .tpl side can you show me on the php side can you post the php file in the question