# How to differentiate array integers and strings and show in smarty tpl file

Tags: php, arrays, smarty

My PHP Code

```
$qry9="SELECT * FROM company_likes WHERE post_id='$pid'";
$result9=mysqli_query($bd, $qry9);
$com_likes= array();
while($row9 = mysqli_fetch_array($result9)){
    $com_likes[]=$row9;
}
```

and displaying this array in tpl file by:

```
{section name=b loop=$com_likes}
{/section}
```

Array `$com_likes[]` contains both integers and strings and I want to differentiate them. If the value is an integer, use a different link from a string in the tpl file.

Comment: which collumns in `company_likes` table?

Comment: Kinds sounds like you want [is_numeric()](https://support.elevatedx.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/206/13/smarty-if-function-is_numeric)

Comment: yes , you are right patrick but how to use in tpl file

Answer (score 1):

You can use PHP functions to determine if it's an integer or not

```
{section name=b loop=$com_likes}
    {if $b|is_numeric}Number Link{else}Text Link{/if}
{/section}
```

Comment: and how can i echo this 'number' , as a name  using SELECT name FROM table WHERE id='number'

Comment: @kuldeep Normally you'd echo it out using something like `{$b}` (using your code). If you need more help than that, check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28316861/passing-variable-from-php-to-smarty) or post a new one with more information